# unable to flush/delete cookie after each request

Tags: java, cookies, siteminder

We are getting HTML login page while hitting Site Minder service using SM Session.

We are getting cookie from httprequest by using httprequest.getcookie().
Please provide some suggestion to delete/flush cookie after each request to get a proper JSON response from site minder service.

We tried to flush out the cookie by using maxagelimit but it didn't worked.

Comment: What are you using to store the cookie after getting it in the `httprequest`? Could you just *not* store or resend the cookie?

Comment: we are not storing it, passing it as header while hitting API

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.